# Error: src refspec master does not match any. when trying to push to Bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a new repo on `Bitbucket` and followed the very simple steps prescribed. First I did `git init` in my local folder to be version controlled. Then I did:

```
git remote add origin https://my_account@bitbucket.org/my_account/my_project.git
```

That worked. The last step was:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I obtained the following:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my_account@bitbucket.org/my_account/my_project.git'
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: did you try pushing without -u flag, it's for adding upstream (tracking) reference. but there is no upstream master branch yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `master` branch.

---

Consider the steps you did:

1. `git init`: this created a new, empty repository, with no commits.

   Given that there are no commits, which branch or branches is / are the commits on?  (This is a somewhat philosophical question, but it deserves your best attempt at an answer.)
2. `git remote add origin url`: this added a *remote*, which is basically just a short name for a URL.  Your otherwise empty repository now has one remote, named `origin`, which is short for the URL.
3. `git push origin master`: this asks your Git to push, to the other Git at the URL specified by the short name `origin`, all the commits that are on your `master` branch, that are not on *their* `master` branch, and then set their `master` branch to point to the same specific *branch tip* commit as your `master` branch.

Now, count all the commits in your repository.  How many are there?  How many commits should you expect your Git to push in step 3?  How many commits are on branch `master`?  Can branch `master` even *exist* if there are no commits on it?  (This gets us back to the philosophical question in step 1.)

---

Now suppose you `git add` some files to your *index* (the index is where you build the *next* commit), and then run `git commit`.  How many commits will you have?  Which branch or branches will the commits be on?  (This question is surprisingly tricky in the end, although in fact the obvious answer—"all of the new commits, which is therefore one single commit, will be on branch `master`"—is the correct answer.)

In Git's world, a branch can *never* be empty—it can never have no commits.  A branch that has no commits simply does not exist.  Weirdly, however, you can be *on* such a branch.  (These branches have two different adjectives used to describe or create them, depending on which Git command or output you're looking at: *unborn branch* and *orphan branch*.)

What it means to be *on a branch* in Git is that your *next* commit, the one you build up in the index, will *extend* that branch, adding a new commit to it.  So the solution to your problem is to make at least one commit while you are on branch `master`, so that branch `master` comes into existence with that first commit you make.  Then you will be able to push it.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone still get this error, try `git add .` and `git commit -m "init"` before `git push origin master`. Hope this helpful .

Comment: I just want to say, I've looked all over google for this and this actually worked. Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried with this. It works.

`git push origin HEAD:<remoteBranch>`